# morphia without map used classes

Tags: java, mongodb, morphia

I saw the snippet like

```
Morphia m = new Morphia();
m.map(Blah.class);
```

is there any undesirable side effect if I skip the second line (the map() method)? I tried, and it can perform CRUD just fine.

Thanks

java mongodb morphia

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Morphia will map classes on the fly for you if you give it a type it hasn't been explicitly asked to map.  This is mostly fine.  You won't, however, be able to take advantage of features like `ensureIndexes()` on those classes or any of the default collation related annotations, e.g.